# Showing output from two different classes in pyqt5 gui python

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, pyside2

### Program

```
import sys 
import os 

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2 import *
from ui_test import *


class MainThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainThread,self).__init__()
        
    def run(self):
        self.task()
        
    def task(self):
        while True:
          com="runnning"
          print(com)
        

startexecution = MainThread()
class main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ti = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ti.setupUi(self)
        self.ti.run_btn.clicked.connect(self.starttask)
        self.ti.close.clicked.connect(self.close)
        
        self.show()
        
        
    
    def starttask(self):
        startexecution.start()
        
        
        

if __name__=="__main__":
    
    app =QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**It is an example of the problem I am facing in my original program**

---

MainThread class run is the main program that runs in the backend and the main class runs GUI in frontend. I want to show the output generated by the backend program in textbrowser of my UI as an output

Comment: 1. Your question is unclear; 2. Don't mix PyQt and PySide, as they are ***NOT*** compatible: either use one or the other.

Comment: Please follow [ask]